# How to get Saved WIFI SSID information (not saved wifi Password) by using adb shell command - on Non-rooted devices?

Tags: android, android-wifi, adb, android-shell

I am trying to find a way by which I can get a list of the remembered networks' SSID on an Android device.

I have seen a few threads asking similar questions. However, the few questions that I have found are trying to get the known network passwords not the SSIDS, but my questions is about Getting the SAVED WIFI SSID by using adb shell command.

Is there any adb shell to get the saved WIFI ssid's?

Answer (score 0):

Most recently on Android O developer preview 3, I can get that info this way (YMMV):

From linux:

```
adb shell bugreport | grep "mSavedSsids:"
```

You can also do it from the shell:

```
bugreport | grep "mSavedSsids:"
```

Just parse the strings that are within the brackets.

"adb bugreport" has been deprecated for the new "adb bugreport ", but the deprecated way still works for me now.